# Quarkus gelf logging. How to log application name

Tags: java, logging, quarkus, elk, gelf

I would like to log application name and version (from pom.xml file) with quarkus-gelf logging to send logs to logstash. I found a way to use "additional-field", is there another option to do same, but shorter? Or some way to not duplicate "version" in both application.yml and pom.xml.

My application.yml

```
...
quarkus:
  log:
    level: INFO
    handler:
      gelf:
        enabled: true
        host: localhost
        port: 12201
        include-log-message-parameters: false
        additional-field:
          app_name:
            value: "testApp"
            type: string
          app_version:
            value: "1.0.0"
            type: string
...
```

My pom.xml

```
...
    <groupId>example.org</groupId>
    <artifactId>testApp</artifactId>
    <name>Testing application</name>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
...
```

Adding

```
quarkus:
  application:
    version: 1.0.0
    name: testApp
```

to application.yml didn't change a thing